# Class for Selected Menu using wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, menus

I create Widget for Vertical menu
Now I am trying to get selected or current menu using **wp_nav_menu**

Any one know how to Add current class when selected in **wp_nav_menu**

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to add a CSS class to the menu item that is currently the active screen?

If so, this is handled in WordPress by default with the ".current-menu-item" CSS class.

Comment: No not showing me that default classess